# What's wrong with this php code? im trying to concatenate

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `deceased` WHERE `birthdate` = '{$birthmonth}'. "-" .'{$birthday}'. "-" .'{$birthyear}'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudn't use dots into the string.
But much better way is avoid to inject variables into the strings and use explicit concats:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `deceased` WHERE `birthdate` = '" . $birthmonth . "-"  . $birthday . "-" . $birthyear . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate your variables inside your quotes as follow

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `deceased` WHERE `birthdate` = '".$birthmonth . "-" . $birthday . "-" . $birthyear."');
```

As side note i would advise you to switch to either [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) since [`mysql_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) api are deprecated and soon will be no longer mantained

Answer (score 0):

From the [`MYSQL` documentation on the `Date` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

So there is a good chance that your query is not getting you what you want since you are searching based on an incorrectly formatted date.  What you want, instead, along with correctly formatted PHP, is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `deceased` WHERE `birthdate` = '$birthyear-$birthmonth-$birthday'");
```